# Wordpress child page showing 404

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

It looks like a lot of people have had similar problems but none of the solutions mentioned have worked for me. Here is the scenario.

Parent pages are working fine, but when i create child pages, they are 404'ing.

Parent is http://localhost/products/dining-chairs/
child is http://localhost/products/dining-chairs/restaurant-chairs/

Permalinks are setup as follows:

/products/%product_cat%/

HTAccess is set as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Hopefully someone can help,

Thanks

Comment: What is you setup of the post links ? It shouldn't be set to default

Comment: Also I'm not sure if you can have such a structure -> /products/%product_cat%/ I think shop should be base for the the product_cat -> /shop/%product_cat%/